# Не могу вызвать codeception на yii2

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Вообщем установил я codeception командой

```
composer global require "codeception/codeception=2.1.*"
```

Все нормально установилось , но вот при вызове codeception buid пишет '

> codecept' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

вызвать его не могу . В документации пишет , что нужно  как-то изменить путь к нему , но я не понимаю как это нужно сделать . Работаю через консоль openserver

Comment: вы пробовали вызвать из консоли vendor/bin/codecept или bin/codecept (в общем, codecept в папке, которая указана в composer.json как bin-dir)?

Comment: Вот смотрите  , я при первой глобальной установке , как и было написано в документации , добавил путь к директрии в переменную окружения PATH . Вот значение ее c:/users/kolya/appdata/roaming/composer/vendor/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\ . и , как я понимаю , после этого команда codecept должна бы стать доступная в консоле  , но "codecept' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"